# Copy and pasting a Python array

Tags: python, arrays, printing

I have a long array of lists of 9 ID numbers that I want to copy and paste into Excel
The output code I am using is

```
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

But in Jupyter the output has the first 8 numbers on the first line and then a new line for the last number so when I copy and paste each value takes up two rows in Excel

[Ouput seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhHFG.jpg)

Is there any easy way to copy the output or widen the Jupyter console to display all 9 values on the same line ?

Answer (score -1):

if it isn't so large you can make a new cell and just write `results` and it will print the arr like this: [id1, id2, .. id9] and then you can copy..

also if you want to do this in large case - you can try this:

```
df = pd.Series(results)
df.head(len(results))
```